# How to find duplicate in a list and update the same list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model 'City' having the following properties

```
publi class City{
            public string CityCode { get; set; }
            public string CityName { get; set; }
            public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

While updating the entries,I check the duplicate only for CityName.If I want to update Remarks I can't do it.Here is my Linq query

```
public void Update(City model)
        {
            var dup = (from c in _CityRepository.TableNoTracking
                       where c.CityName.Equals(model.CityName)
                       select c.CityName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (dup == null)
            {
                City city = new City();
                city.CityCode=model.CityCode;
                city.CityName = model.CityName;
                city.Remarks = (model.Remarks==null)?string.Empty:model.Remarks;
                _CityRepository.Update(city);
             }
        }
```

If I want to check duplicate Cityname Except for that CityCode means How to do that?

Comment: In Update method I'm finding the duplicates of CityName .If I Want to update the Remarks,Its not Updating.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `dup` is name of city. It's better to use `Any` operator to check if there exists city with same name:

```
bool exists = _CityRepository.TableNoTracking
                 .Any(c => c.CityName == model.CityName);
```

But it's not enough to only check if city exists. You need to get saved entity and update it with values from model. For searching city by name, you can use overloaded [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039(v=vs.100).aspx) operator which accepts predicate:

```
var city = _CityRepository.TableNoTracking
              .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CityName == model.CityName);
```

Then check if city was found and update it with values from model (you don't need to update city name, because you searched by name):

```
if (city != null)
{
    city.CityCode = model.CityCode;
    city.Remarks = model.Remarks ?? string.Empty;
    _CityRepository.Update(city);
}
else
{
    // there is no match, so you need to create new city and save it
}
```

Also keep in mind that city name might be not unique. It's better to search by city code. And if you don't need to update code and name, you can just update remarks.

Comment: @Indhu you are searching by CityName (e.g. London) and you want to update city name of found city. What do you think - which value would have CityName of found city?

Comment: @Indhu also check whether CityName check should be case sensitive or not, it will be better to have it as case sensitive

Comment: After your update - `Any(c => c.CityName == model.CityName && c.CityCode != model.CityCode)`. Try to explain your goal better. Instead of  *"I want to check duplicate Cityname Except for that CityCode means"* use *"I want to check whether exists city with same name, but other code"*

Answer (score 0):

Using this query I can find the existence of CityName

```
 var dup = (from c in _CityRepository.TableNoTracking
                           where c.CityName.Equals(model.CityName) && c.CityCode!=model.CityCode
                           select c.CityName).FirstOrDefault();
```